# In the British game show Countdown, how are the numbers 6 and 9 differentiated?

Tags: game-show, countdown

When Rachel Riley (and Carol Vorderman before her) pull the small numbers from the stack for the numbers round, how is the number six differentiated from the number nine?

Do they just keep track of the orientation and the logo on the back?  Usually board games in this situation would have it underlined to make sure it's not upside down.

Or does it simply not matter, since if it's flipped upside-down it's still random?

Comment: Rachel Riley is [highly active on twitter](https://twitter.com/RachelRileyRR) so I suppose you could ask her...

Comment: You could try watching carefully and seeing if all the numbers are the same way up when they're gathered and then placed on the rack. This would indicate that 6 and 9 are placed the opposite way up before the game, and that order is reproduced. Just a guess.

Answer (score 5):

> Or does it simply not matter, since if it's flipped upside-down it's still random?

The internet appears to believe there should only be two examples of each number 1-10 available, so it does matter.

According to [the Countdown wiki](https://wiki.apterous.org/Main_Page), at least in the early days this has sometimes led to confusion:

[Episode 79](https://wiki.apterous.org/Episode_79)

> Episode 79 was broadcast on 1 July 1983, and was the second semi-final
> of Series 2.
>
> ... It appears that three 9's were selected for the Round 8 numbers
> game; it is likely that one of the 9's was an upside down 6.

[Episode 103](https://wiki.apterous.org/Episode_103)

> Episode 103 was broadcast on 26 October 1983, as part of Series 3.
>
> ...
>
> It appears that three 6's were selected for the Round 4 numbers game;
> it is likely that one of the 6's was an upside down 9.

I can't readily find later examples so I would speculate that a procedure was changed. That wiki is still active so its participants may know more.